# Do I use NSAttributedString or UIWebView Swift

Tags: ios, swift, uiwebview, uitextview, nsattributedstring

I'm getting different strings that occupy "busDescriptio" depending on what business you choose from a website database. This string contains html tags, images, and links. I was told to use NSAttributedString instead of UIWebView because UIWebView was giving me all sorts of problems such as images in wrong place, text font, and text color wouldn't fully work. I'm new to Swift so I cant really wrap my head around how NSAttributedString works. I was able to strip out the html tags and keep the font but that took away images, links, ext. with this

```
let encodedString = "\(busDescriptio)"
            let encodedData = encodedString.dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding)!
            let attributedOptions = [NSDocumentTypeDocumentAttribute: NSHTMLTextDocumentType]
            let attributedString = NSAttributedString(data: encodedData, options: attributedOptions, documentAttributes: nil, error: nil)

            let decodedString = attributedString?.string
```

and I loaded it into a UITextView

```
// Create UITextView
            var textView = UITextView(frame: CGRectMake(0, 95.0, screenWidth-10, 300.0))
            textView.text = decodedString
            textView.font = UIFont.preferredFontForTextStyle(UIFontTextStyleBody)

            border.addSubview(textView)
```

I dont like how any of this works so here is what I'm trying to do. 
- I wanting to change the font size, font color, and take in images with my string(busDescriptio). Do I use UIWebView to get this done or NSAttributedString? If so how can I do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
extension String {
    var html2AttStr:NSAttributedString {
        return NSAttributedString(data: dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding)!, options:[NSDocumentTypeDocumentAttribute:NSHTMLTextDocumentType, NSCharacterEncodingDocumentAttribute: NSUTF8StringEncoding], documentAttributes: nil, error: nil)!
    }
}

let yourAttributedText = "<style type=\"text/css\">#red{color:#F00}#green{color:#0F0}#blue{color: #00F; font-weight: Bold; font-size: 32}</style><span id=\"red\" >Red,</span><span id=\"green\" > Green </span><span id=\"blue\">and Blue</span>".html2AttStr

textView.attributedText = yourAttributedText
```

Comment: I see that you are using an extnesion which is what I should probably do in my case. How would I call my busDescriptio to that extension then put it into my textView? or do use something different to put my string and text into?

Comment: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UITextView_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UITextView/attributedText

Comment: Okay I figured it out! I use the #id and add all the css scripting to it and then use <span>id</span> then my \(busDescription). Thanks for the help! plus one for help and answer

Comment: Yes you just need to select which style you want to use inside your spam using the desired style ID

Answer (score 2):

An attributed string is a string with attributes.

The `string` property returns the string without attributes.

You're building a string with attributes, throwing away all the attributes, then handing just the text to the text view.

Set `attributedString` to the text view's `attributedText` property to give it the attributes.

Comment: Okay I set it wrong at first. It works! Thanks but how can I customize these properties like move change font color and size, or move the pictures it loads to the left?

Comment: Plus 1 for giving the explanation what I was doing wrong and telling me how to set it!