# Convert unicode value to character in string using swift

Tags: ios, string, swift, unicode

I am getting below texts from service `"and apparently didn&#8217;t leave"` I want this text will be converted as `"and apparently didn't leave"`. How would I do it using swift language?

I was reading below doc but not able to figure out any solutions.

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/StringsAndCharacters.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH7-ID301

Thanks

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/27662573/2303865

Comment: Take a look at this one also http://stackoverflow.com/a/28870351/2303865